# How to export a useContext variable without having to call useContext on each components?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-functional-component

I wrote a toast context and wrap the whole project in the toast provider. If one of my components need to use toast, it will call

```
function Component() {
   const toast = useToast();
   toast.success("")
   ...
}
```

Is there anyway to just import toast directly without having to call useToast() on individual components as below?

```
import { toast } from "./toast-provider.tsx"

function Component() {
   toast.success("")
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `toast` is a something like `<React.createContext().Provider />`.

In this case it is not possible to call `toast.attribute`, at least according to my understanding. You would have to use a Higher order component for classes, and in your case, the `useContext` hook or something similar for functional components.

If you would like to be able to access an attribute of `toast` with dot notation, `toast` would have to be e.g. an Object. That would be one possibility to create contexts:

```js
function getAttr2() {
  return "some dynamic value";
}

export const toast = {
  attribute1: "some attribute",
  attribute2: getAttr2()
};
```

But that would of course not be in accordance with how React uses context.

Comment: My useToast is basically "export const useToast = () => useContext(ToastContext);". Your suggestion doesn not work in my case though, since my toast provider use react-toastitfy and need to have a component attached at the end of the provider, not just pure global function. Thanks for your answer.